# this second param (radix) of parseInt method

Tags: javascript

I found a snippet using `parseInt`; it is used to get the window height.

This is the code:

```
parseInt($(window).height(), 20);
```

I am confused about why this uses 20 as the second parameter. Why not 10?

Answer (score 2):

Either:

- Someone really wants to work in Base 20
- Someone pressed the key next to <kbd>1</kbd> by accident

You would need to ask the person who wrote the code. We can't know for sure without a lot more context.